# Increment Year in a for loop

Tags: r

I am trying to write a loop that performs year to year analysis on my data set.  I am new to R, but in other programming languages, I would do something similar to data2$YEAR_RISK +1, but this doesn't seem to be working.  My code is below:

```
for(i in 1:nrow(data2))
data2$Results[i] <-
  ifelse(data2$Change[i] < 0, print(
    paste(
      "From", data2$YEAR_RISK [i], "to", data2$YEAR_RISK +1[i],     data2$RESOURCE_UTILIZATION_BAND[i], "decreased by", data2$Change[i]
    )
  ), ifelse(data2$Change[i] > 0 ,print(
    paste(
      "From", data2$YEAR_RISK[i], "to", data2$YEAR_RISK +1[i],   data2$RESOURCE_UTILIZATION_BAND[i], "increased by", data2$Change[i]
    )
  ),"0"))
```

The result I get is "From 2015 to 2015 0 decreased by -0.02" when I want it to say "From 2014 to 2015 0 decreased by -0.02". Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: In your code, you have `data2$YEAR_RISK +1[i]`, it should be `data$YEAR_RISK[i] + 1`

Answer (score 1):

On of the many good thing with R is that most functions will work very well with vectors. In your case, there is no need of a `for` loop, and you could just write:

```
data2$Results <- paste("From", data2$YEAR_RISK, "to", data2$YEAR_RISK + 1, data2$RESSOURCE_UTILIZATION_BAND, ifelse(data2$Change == 0, "0", ifelse(data2$Change < 0, "decreased by", "increased by"), data2$Change))
```